# Linux - create animated gif with pan and zoom

Tags: linux, node.js, terminal

I am looking for a Linux command line utility that can allow me to create an animated gif from an existing image, and then apply panning and/or zooming to create the animated gif. I have looked into a few such as ImageMagick, but found nothing to help with this. I need something that is either a command line utility or a node module. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this with ImageMagick - I can't make it bigger or smoother without exceeding StackOverflow's maximum upload, but you can change the `steps` parameter to 100 and also the `-resize` to `-resize 500x400` locally on your machine:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Panned and zoomed animation
# Mark Setchell
#
steps=40
# Final x offset from top left
finalx=2800
# Final y offset from top left
finaly=1400
# Initial & Final width
initw=4000
finalw=1000
# Initial & Final height
inith=3200
finalh=800

# Remove anything from previous attempts
rm frame-*jpg 2> /dev/null
for i in $(seq 0 $steps); do
   ((x=finalx*i/steps))
   ((y=finaly*i/steps))
   ((w=initw-(i*(initw-finalw)/steps)))
   ((h=inith-(i*(inith-finalh)/steps)))
   echo $i,$x,$y,$w,$h
   name=$(printf "frame-%03d.jpg" $i)
   convert elcap.jpg -crop ${w}x${h}+${x}+${y} -resize 200x160 "$name"
done
convert -delay 20 frame* anim.gif
```

[image]

Apple's copyright of the gorgeous image used on OSX El Capitan's desktop is acknowledged.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it and it works, just not as fast as I need it to work. I am generating 10s of thousands of videos a day and the process is incredibly fast. I need something that is a little faster that doesn't create a separate image for each frame. It also doesn't have a smooth zoom/pan. It jumps between images.

Comment: This script is fantastic. If the output is too choppy, you can increase the number of frames and decrease the delay between frames (takes longer but looks nicer)

Comment: If you are making lots of these, you can make the input image filename an input argument to the script, then pipe the output of an `ls` command to `xargs myscript.sh`, and pass the `-j <N>` flag to xargs to run N jobs in parallel. (You would also need to change the "frame-%03d.jpg" intermediate filenames to something unique so the parallel jobs don't squash each other.)