# Create sliding video from pattern/tile image

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Given a 300x300 tile image like [this](https://patterncooler.com/gen/downloaded/jpg/_s_a12Cb12Cc12Cd12Ce0f0g64h2D345BF0F0DBiF1j0k64l1F4m1F4.jpg) I would like to generate a 1920x1080 video just showing the repeated tile (i.e. tiles are repeated in order to cover all the 1920x1080) but also slowly moving from left to right.

Using ImageMagick I know how to generate a very long image from the tile image, let say a 19200x1080 image:

```
magick convert -size 19200x1080 tile:tile.jpg long.jpg
```

But I have no idea on how to use ffmpeg in order to crop a 1920x1080 area from the long image and move the crop area horizontally as time passes.

Any help, also with a completely different approach not based on the long image generated by ImageMagick ?

Comment: See [my answer to another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71120424/4516027). If you have any question, edit your post with your attempt and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: My attempt is basically none. I have the 300x300 tile image. And I could generate the 19200x1080 long image. From there I need a ffmpeg command able to produce the video. I'm not able to "adapt" the other question/answer, which is based on "hundreds of input images". I just have one single image.

Comment: I did a pan-and-zoom thing aeons ago... https://stackoverflow.com/a/33467267/2836621

Comment: Ok got it from @kesh answer, thanks!
`ffmpeg -y -r 1 -i long.jpg -vf 'fps=30,crop=w=1920:h=1080:x=mod(n\,30)*1080/30:y=0' -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4`

Comment: You can also do the tiling in FFmpeg by prepending [`tile` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tile-1) to the `vf` filtergraph and tweaking input options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with my Imagemagick (bash unix) script, overlapcrop. It will do overlap cropping and then make your animation as one output option. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/overlapcrop/index.php

Input:

[image]

```
# do tiling to a 600x300 larger image as an example:

magick -size 600x300 tile:pattern_blue_and_white.jpg pattern_long.jpg


# do overlap crop and make animation:

overlapcropxx -s 300x300 -o 290x0 -m animation -z 2 -d 30 pattern_long.jpg pattern_animation.gif
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This ImageMagick command will create a series of 30 images, 1920x1080, tiled with the 300x300 (or almost any size) input image, and each moving to the left 1/30 the width of the input image more than the last. The output is saved as a GIF, which may then be used as a multi-image input to ffmpeg to make a video.

```
magick tile.png -duplicate 29 -roll -%[fx:t*w/n]+0 ^
   -set option:distort:viewport 1920x1080 ^
   -virtual-pixel tile -distort srt 0 tiles.gif
```

The command is in Windows syntax. For *nix change the continued line carets "^" to backslashes "\", or just put it all on one line.

This ffmpeg command reads the image created above, and extends it to about a 10 second loop video.

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop 9 -r 30 -i tiles.gif tiles.mp4
```

Adjust the number of duplicates in the ImageMagick command and the input frame rate in ffmpeg for smoothness and speed.

EDITED: To correct number of stream_loops in the ffmpeg command.

Comment: `-stream_loop 10` repeats the input 10 times, so total 11 playbacks.